# Type in Instagram's Search Bar using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, instagram

I’m trying to select a search bar using selenium web driver in python. The problem is that the class names and a lot of the css values are generated dynamically. What would be the best way to select the search bar to submit a search?

When I inspect, the search bar is dynamic:

[image: Search Bar Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the 'placeholder="Search"' bit is always the same then you could do:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")

searchbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search']")
    )
)
```

To get the elemt by an XPATH based on that attribute being set on the field.